# Value binding to existing HTML elements

Tags: ember.js

As Emberjs suggests in order to bind elements values/attributes etc.. to controllers I have to create that element using Emberjs. For example:

```
App.SearchTextField = Em.TextField.extend({ });
```

and the view:

```
{{view App.SearchTextField placeholder="Twitter username"
                           valueBinding="App.tweetsController.username"}}
```

This means that pretty much the entire content of the page should be under Emberjs control. This isn't very convenient.

Is is possible to do any type of value or event binding to an existing element?

Answer (score 1):

In order for bindings to work, Ember needs to know when a bound value changes so that it syncs it.  For Ember to know that a value has changed, you need to use `Ember.set`. Example:

```
object.set('value', 'I changed'); 
// This says: Ember, my value has changed, please sync!
```

So, when a certain property changes without using `Ember.set`, Ember doesn't know that it should sync it.  As a result, we need to listen to this event change, and tell Ember that it changed using `Ember.set`.

That's what happens on input values.  When you type, the value changes, but `Ember.set` was not called.  So what `Ember.TextField` does, is listen to `keyup` and `change` and other events and calls `Ember.set` when one of these events is fired.

Of course, you don't *have* to use them, but then you will have to manually listen to these changes and tell Ember that the value changed: `this.set('value', this.$().val())`)

I don't see why you have a problem with using `Ember.TextField` as it can do almost anything, and all it does it save you the trouble of listening to the events yourself.

One thing that might help you is that you can directly use it in your template, instead of creating a view to extend it:

```
{{view Em.TextField placeholder="Twitter username" valueBinding="username" type="search"}}
```

which is almost the same amount of typing as:

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Twitter username" value="some value" />
```

Note: From the example you provided above, it looks like you are following an old tutorial, be careful, lots have changed since then.

Comment: Thank you! TO answer you question, the only problem with that is the fact that then most of the UI has to be done on the client, which might become quite slow especially on IE. Imagine yourself a part of admin panel that deals with ~1000 elements, what happens then?

Comment: You need to render in JS regardless of whether you can bind attributes directly or need to use a view.  That's how Ember works, rendering in JS is a given. If you are having performance issues with ~1000 elements, then either rethink your UI (~1000 elements is a lot), or I guess rethink whether Ember is the best fit for this project.